# select with special characters not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a select box  which is

```
<select>
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option id="402883273d3fe2bd013d49db55ca0007" value="~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\:" title="~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\:">~`!@#$%^&amp;*()_+-={}|[]\:</option>
<option id="402883273b660e71013b6ff04187000d" value="asdasd" title="asdasd">asdasd</option>
<option id="402883273952e67f01395332fd5f0006" value="CC-1" title="CC-1">CC-1</option>
<option id="402883273bdb9824013c14d3c2c30007" value="rto" title="rto">rto</option>
<option id="402883273bdb9824013c14d5decf0008" value="xc" title="xc">xc</option>
</select>
```

and now when i am loading the page and to select option with value = "~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\:"
its not getting selected.

code for selection is :

```
var selectedCategory = "<%=StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(toEditClause.getClauseGroup().getClauseCategory().getName())%>";
        console.log("before : "+selectedCategory);
        selectedCategory = selectedCategory.replace(/'/g,"\\'");
        console.log("After : "+selectedCategory);
        jQuery("#clauseCategory_ option[value='"+selectedCategory+"']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

i think problem is due to special characters because otherwise if i choose some other value like : "CC-1" .. its working fine

Comment: Is there no other way you can select that option? Via a class maybe, or index? You can also try setting the value via `val()`: `jQuery("#clauseCategory_").val(selectedCategory;`

Comment: try urlencoding the values ..

Comment: Escape the special characters using `\\\`

Comment: what do you mean by not getting selected - do you mean.. you are unable to select in browser... (or) you are not getting the selected value into selectedCategory ...

Comment: I have just verified IE8 browser and i am able to select the option in the browser... pls check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of value go for the ID.. ie select on the bases of ID .. so use this `jQuery("#clauseCategory_ option[id='"+selectedCategory+"']").attr("selected", "selected");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [solution](http://totaldev.com/content/escaping-characters-get-valid-jquery-id):

```
// Escapes special characters and returns a valid jQuery selector
function jqSelector(str)
{
    return str.replace(/([;&,\.\+\*\~':"\!\^#$%@\[\]\(\)=>\|])/g, '\\$1');
}
```